# REST API to see the file content in storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

In azure via rest calls, for a particular storage account, I have files stored in Storage accounts >  File service  > directory > my files. But using rest API i am only able to see the directory. I am unable to see the files stored under that directory. And more specifically I want to see the content of the file.Is there ant rest API for the above?

Comment: Share your code here please

Comment: A quick web search for 'file service rest api' should give you all you need.

Comment: @VedPrakash, when  I do GET call using : 
https:/<storage account name>.file.core.windows.net/?comp=list .  then on passing headers as :x-ms-date,x-ms-version and Authorization. then I get a response  like :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnumerationResults ServiceEndpoint="https://<storage account name>.file.core.windows.net/">
   
<Name>XYZ</Name>
          
</EnumerationResults>.

Comment: Hi @AmitNautiyal, as you did, [List Shares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-shares) can help us return a list of the shares under the specified account. Besides, you can list directories and files using [List Directories and Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-directories-and-files), read file using [Get File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file). The Rest API works for me, for details, you can refer to my reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to the error message you mentioned, during authorization shared key generation we need to use the URL which we are invoking not the previous authorisation shared key which you mentioned.

So each time when we use different URL for example : List Shared Files, Get Directories, Get Files, we need to use that particular URL during authorisation shared key generation.

https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myshare/mydirectorypath?restype=directory&comp=list

I am sure this will work perfectly in your case.

Comment: One one hit from my side

Answer (score 0):

To list the shares under the specified account, you can use:

> GET https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/?comp=list

[image]

To read (or download) a file, you can use:

> GET https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myshare/mydirectorypath/myfile

[image]

Besides, you can perform the [List Directories and Files operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-directories-and-files) to return a list of files or directories under the specified share or directory.

More file share operations are listed in [File Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/file-service-rest-api), you can refer to it.